# Install all avaiable languages for windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language

I want to install all available languages for windows 10 so that windows can display all foreign characters.

I tried to install them via the settings but there are alot of languages and I'd have to click all of them what would take quite a while:

[image: screenshot]

I also can't multiselect them (with the CTRL key for example).

**Is there a simple way to install all available languages so my operating system can display every existing character?**

Comment: don't do this, Windows will now take ages to install new update rollups.

Comment: It also won't accomplish what the author wants :-). Language packs only apply to the Windows you not third-party program

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install language packs to display all characters from all languages. Normally your Windows will print all characters properly. Installing language packs will only give you possibility to view Windows applications in other languages and use their keyboards. No need to do that.

Comment: Hm that's strange. Somehow windows doesn't display (for example) japanese characters in the cmd. Is the cmd somehow a special case?

Comment: Cmd is Unicode, so with proper codepage it should display all characters. You need to change the codepage.

Comment: It's strange, also the default text editor (notepad) only displays question marks instead of foreign characters.

Comment: @MichaelPittino That sounds like an encoding issue. The file you’re trying to display is probably not UTF-8 (or whatever) but using a legacy encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading them from here: https://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/installation/downloads/Pages/Windows-10-Language-Interface-Packs.aspx

[How to:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/add-language-interface-packs-to-windows)

Install LIPs

To install a LIP using audit mode (used for manufacturing PCs)

- Download the appropriate LIP (and if necessary, its base language), and save it to removable media.
- Boot the destination computer to audit mode. For example at the OOBE screen, press Ctrl+Shift+F3. To learn more, see Boot Windows to Audit Mode or OOBE.
- Insert the removable media and copy the LIP (and base language, if necessary) to the destination computer.
- If the base language isn't already installed, install it: Navigate to the .cab file and double-click it. Follow the instructions to complete the installation.
- Install the LIP: Navigate to the .cab file and double-click it. Follow the instructions to complete the installation.
- Exit audit mode and prepare the PC for image capture or deployment, for example:

Open a command prompt and run:

`sysprep /oobe /generalize`

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. It still does each language one at a time ...